# Removing duplicates from many excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I got a question if there is any fast way to remove duplicate rows across two excel spreadsheets. After searching I can do it by comparing the same rows in the spreadsheets (VBA). But I want to check whether the row from one is included anywhere in two. If exactly the same row exists in two it should be removed. So far I can do it if they are the same rows (e.g. 1 and 1).
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you have anything to show us that you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a workaround for this:

1. Create a column at the end of each row which is concatenation of all the columns of that particular row: Lets sat below are the two tables on the two excel sheets:

sheet1

```
A   B   C   D(Concat)
1   2   3   123
4   5   6   456
7   8   9   789
1   3   5   135
4   3   2   432
```

sheet2

```
A   B   C   D(Concat)
2   3   4   234
1   1   1   111
1   2   3   123
2   2   2   222
4   5   6   456
```

2. We will now identify the duplicate rows based on the last concatenated column. Using the formula
    `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4,Sheet1!D:D,0)),"DUP","NONDUP")`
    in the second sheet, we can identify the rows which are already present in sheet1 irrespective of the sequence of the row in sheet1 wrt sheet2.

Result on Sheet2 shows up as below:

```
A   B   C   D   E(Result)
2   3   4   234 NONDUP
1   1   1   111 NONDUP
1   2   3   123 DUP
2   2   2   222 NONDUP
4   5   6   456 DUP
```